# Drop or truncate a temporary table during LOAD DATA?

Tags: mysql, batch-processing

I'm using `LOAD DATA` to batch csv content into a `TEMPORARY` table, with deactivated auto-commit. Within the same transaction, I then `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` the content from temp table into the production table. After that, I `COMMIT` the transaction.

I have several files, and each of them runs the transaction described above.

Question: should I `DROP` and recreate the temporary table before each commit? Because I don't need the data in the temporary table anymore, plus I need a fresh temporary table for each file import.
Or should I better simply `TRUNCATE` the temporary table?

Comment: Both are same only either or DROP & recreate, Truncate will internal do same DROP & recreate. But still if no other concern go with TRUNCATE because everything will be managed itself.

Comment: *should I DROP and recreate the temporary table before each commit?* If the structures of previous and next temptables are the same then TRUNCATE is enough. Else - DROP is more safe then TRUNCATE + ALTER TABLE.